# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[ClaimBuildMVC.Models.UserDetail]' to type 'System.Co

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am New to MVC with Entity framework using LINQ and i am getting following error

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery 1[BuildMVC.Models.UserDetail]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[System.Object]'

Below is the Code

```
public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{       
    IList<dynamic> GetRecord(long Id);      
    void Add(TEntity entity);
    void update(TEntity entity);
}

public IList<dynamic> GetRecord(long Id)
{
    var _lstUser=(IList<dynamic>)(from ud in _dbContext.UserDetails
                                  join rs in _dbContext.RolesMasters
                                  on ud.FkRoleId equals rs.ID
                                  select new UserDetail
                                  {
                                      FirstName = ud.FirstName + " " + ud.LastName,
                                      PostalStreet=rs.RoleName, 
                                      IsDeleted=ud.IsDeleted
                                  });
    return _lstUser;
}
```

I am fetching the `rs.RoleName` column from second table but since i have used `UserDetail` class so  i have taken `PostalStreet` column from `UserDetail`, don't know this is the correct way or not.

Comment: Why are you trying to cast it to `dynamic`? Remove the `(IList<dynamic>)`

Comment: public IList<dynamic> GetRecord(long Id)
        {

            var _lstUser=(IList<dynamic>)(from ud in _dbContext.UserDetails join  rs in _dbContext.RolesMasters
                            on ud.FkRoleId equals rs.ID
                                          select new UserDetail
                            {FirstName=ud.FirstName+" "+ud.LastName,PostalStreet=rs.RoleName,IsDeleted=ud.IsDeleted}
                             )  ;
            return _lstUser;
        }

Comment: Edit your question and delete the unreadable comment. And again, what is the reason for casting to dynamic (and making it unusable in your view. but if you really want to do this, then add `.ToList()` to your query.

Comment: I am using Generic Repository Pattern and there i have define something like this IList<dynamic> GetRecord(long Id); and i am implementing which is already shown in comments. What to edit can you please elaborate rather than downvote

Comment: Click the 'edit' link below the question and edit your code.

Comment: Just add `.ToList()` to the end of your query - `... IsDeleted=ud.IsDeleted }).ToList();` (but returning `dynamic` is an awful way to do this)

Comment: did the same thing but got an error "{"The entity or complex type 'CBMultiTenancyModel.UserDetail' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query."}"

Comment: In that case you probably need to use `.ToList()` before the `select` - `(from .....).ToList().Select( x => new UserDetail { ..... }.ToList();`. But you method name is `GetRecord()` which suggests you want 1 record, not a collection. Hard to understand why you doing any of this.

Comment: well thanks man for your patience but believe me it is getting complex for me :(  attach is the error ![Valid XHTML](http://imgur.com/CUFiTbT)

Comment: I see now - `UserDetail` is a mapped entity - you cannot project on to a mapped entity. But since you don't even need a model, just an anonymous type, use your original code but change `select new UserDetail` to just `select new` (and then add .ToList()` at the end. But your still going about this all wrong and your just creating a rod for you own back by returning `dynamic` instead of `TEntity`

Comment: Ok.just altered my code and changes to IList<dynamic> to IList<TEntity> as you directed but still came "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType6`3[System.String,System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean]]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[ClaimBuildMVC.Models.UserDetail]'."}"

Comment: No. The code I gave you was to use your current `dynamic`. If you now want to change it to `IList<UserDetail>` you need to project the anonymous collection in to a collection of `UserDetail`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public static IEnumerable<CustomerOrder> GetCustomerOrder(this IRepository<Customer> repository, string country)
    {
        var customers = repository.GetRepository<Customer>().Queryable();
        var orders = repository.GetRepository<Order>().Queryable();
        var query = from c in customers
            join o in orders on new {a = c.CustomerID, b = c.Country}
                equals new {a = o.CustomerID, b = country}
            select new CustomerOrder
            {
                CustomerId = c.CustomerID,
                ContactName = c.ContactName,
                OrderId = o.OrderID,
                OrderDate = o.OrderDate
            };

        return query.AsEnumerable();
    }
```

Here I have created extra class which will have variables from both the classes which are being used in WebGrid.